# List to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm forecasting multiple times series using Prophet of Facebook and the results of the forecast are on a listbut I would like to get them on a dataframe. Can you help me? Thanks

[Results of forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOERt.png)

Comment: Consider adding some images of what you have now, also add some portion of the code or an idea of what you are attemping to do

Comment: pd.DataFrame accepts lists as input

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using python's .split() method in some loop to separate the values in each list element. The split method takes a delimiter which would be white space, " " in your case. After this you'll have a 2D list
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Then I'd consider importing pandas and convert from 2D list to dataframe using .DataFrame()
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

example:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: splitting is for strings not lists

Comment: Oh, i though the contents of the list was one big string that needed to be separated

Comment: ah true..it looks like a list of dicts? but could be wrong